# adding com.android.support:design causes failed to resolve R error

Tags: android, gradle, floating-action-button

I am working on an android project where in activity_main layout i wish to add a floating action button.However as soon as i try to use it android studio ask to add  `com.android.support:support-v4:20.1.0`.

However, if I add it into my project it causes `R` cannot be resolve error whereas I am unable to use  floating action button if i don't add this library.

What should i do?

Comment: Go to `Files -> Invalidate Caches & Restart` and click `invalidate & restart` button on dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add support design library in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:20.1.0'
```

or

```
compile'com.android.support:design:20.1.0'
```

depending of your gradle version

Comment: Yup ,but if i add , it causes R cannot be resolve error

Comment: Add it, clean the project and finally rebuild, try it and tell me if works.